# How do width and height, work with positions: relative, absolute, fixed?

Tags: html, css, height, width, css-position

How do CSS `width` and `height` properties operate with positions: `relative`, `absolute`, `fixed`?

I mean:

- `width` and `height` are measurements relative to the element they are defining?

or

- `width` and `height` are measurements relative to the positioned father of the element?

Comment: Do you mean, for example, width: 50%?

Comment: all of them behave the same regarding width/height. The only difference is the *containing block* which is the reference of percentage value: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details

Comment: sorry, yes: i wanted to say: width height, working with percentages %

Answer (score -2):

Setting a percentage value of either height or width while the element is positioned as `fixed` or `absolute` takes the base of calculation as element's parent dimensions. By parent I mean `viewport` when `fixed` and direct parent then `absolute`

Comment: it's not the body for fixed element but the viewport